# How can I use XML parameter with if/else condition

Tags: html, xml, xslt, frontend

I have a XML parameter (discount). I want to use it as if discount exist, display Discount. Otherwise display nothing. I've tried an example but I know it is wrong way.How can I use it?

```
<xmlparameter>    
  <paymentinfo taxbase="187,97 $" subtotal="205,12 $" discount="10,00 $"     total="227,12 $" 
  totalinstallment="250,54 TL" />
</xmlparameter>

   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$discount">
        <tr style="font-size:14px;">
          <td colspan="2">
            Discount:
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="paymentinfo/@discount"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl></xsl>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Which data type is your param going to have, string, boolean, number, node-set, or result tree fragment? Do you want to check whether it has been set to something different than the default set?

Comment: @MartinHonnen boolean number  and string. for example 7,00 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is no need of using `<xsl:choose>` here as you only want to display if it exists, so a simple `<xsl:if>` will do the trick.

But anyway this is not the question...

So to check if it exists, you could convert it to a `String` (I'm not sure what is the type as it is not specified and we don't see where the parameter is initialized) then check if empty. Your code would look like this :

```
<xsl:if test="string($discount) != ''">
    <tr style="font-size:14px;">
        <td colspan="2"><xsl:text>Discount:</xsl:text></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="paymentinfo/@discount"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:if>
```